# How do I create multiple instances of a object in javascript during runtime?

Tags: javascript, object

Trying to finish up an assignment and I can't seem to find get around this:
Here's what is being asked:

*"Your JavaScript program should parse the user’s inputs. For each input, you should create a JavaScript object of Shopper to hold the data parsed from user’s input. Make sure that each object should have a property named “Items” which should have an string array of items as value, e.g. [“Milk”, “Shoes”, “Phone”]."*

Here is what I've done so far:

```
var shopper = {
  first_name : "",
  last_name : "",
  email  : "",
  items: []
};

var flag = true;
var x = 0;
while (flag == true) {

  var temp_obj = prompt("Please enter your first name, last name, email and items separated by ,");
  if (temp_obj == "" || temp_obj == null) {
    flag = false;
  }

/*Here I'm suppose to create instances of the object..Have no idea how. this is what I think might work.
var shopper[x] = Object.create(shopper);
x++
*/

}
```

Comment: You may find [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) and [that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) links very useful. The answer to your question (and more) are in those links. Good luck =]

Comment: You cannot create an "instance of an object". An object is already an instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you can do it with a factory function

Click <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> to see it work.

To finish inputting items, click <kbd>OK</kbd> with an empty line.

```js
// Shopper constructor
function Shopper(firstName, lastName, email, items) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName  = lastName;
  this.email     = email;
  this.items     = items;
}

// Shopper factory function
// takes user input with comma-separated terms
// inputs[0] = firstName
// inputs[1] = lastName
// inputs[2] = email
// inputs[3..] = items
Shopper.create = function create(str) {
  var inputs = str.split(', ');
  return new Shopper(inputs[0], inputs[1], inputs[2], inputs.slice(3));
};

// a list of all shoppers
var shoppers = [];

// continue collecting user inputs until user enters a blank line
var response;
while (response = prompt("firstName, lastName, email, item1, item2, item3, ...")) {

  // add shopper to the `shoppers` array
  shoppers.push(Shopper.create(response));
}

// display all shoppers
alert(JSON.stringify(shoppers, null, "\t"));
```

Sample user inputs

```
a, b, c@example.com, milk, candy, eggs
x, y, z@example.com, meat, cereal, yams
```

Output

```json
[
    {
        "firstName": "a",
        "lastName": "b",
        "email": "c@example.com",
        "items": [
            "milk",
            "candy",
            "eggs"
        ]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "x",
        "lastName": "y",
        "email": "z@example.com",
        "items": [
            "meat",
            "cereal",
            "yams"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: I'd like to see a validation of the input before the `Shopper` is created `if (inputs.length >= 4)`. Also, the `create` function will be needlessly replicated on every `Shopper` object

Comment: @Jan, I don't write defensive software, nor do I recommend it. There's always a better way.

Comment: @Jan, you are wrong. The `Shopper.create` function exists as a property of the `Shopper` constructor function. Each instance will not inherit the property. But, even if it *was* attached to the `Shopper.prototype`, it still would only exist as a *single* function. -- You can think of this difference as *class* methods vs *instance* methods in traditional OOP.

Comment: Yeah I stand corrected, I had my prototypes all mixed up. Damn, long since I worked with them. What's your beef with defensive programming? Granted, not a fan of validation myself but thought that in this case it would be warranted. Maybe not the right place to do it though...

Comment: Nice answer Naomik. However, I want to be able to make instances like this: 
shopper1.first_name = joe;
shopper2.first_name = dan;

I need to manipulate the values in each instance of the object later in the assignment. You answer seem to have array of shoppers

Comment: @Jan, it's pointless as you'll never be able to defend against all of the cases. Instead just use strict APIs correctly. For example, `prompt` will always return a `string` 100% of the time. Notice, I wrote `Shopper.create` to accept a string, and it will always yield a `Shopper` object 100% of the time. I can call `str.split` without even checking for a `string` type because i'm enforcing that a string *must* be used. If you call `Shopper.create` without a string, that is your fault, not the function's fault, and it should do nothing to help you if you use it incorrectly.

Comment: @Jan, and if you want to use the more complex, but equally reliable `Shopper` constructor, it takes 3 `string` arguments and 1 `array` argument and it will work 100% of the time.

Comment: @acer, if you ever catch yourself numbering your varialbes like `shopper1`, `shopper2`, etc, it's a hint that you should be using an array instead -- You can access individual shoppers via the `shoppers` array I created in my answer. Arrays are 0-indexed, meaning the first item in the array starts with 0. `shoppers[0]`  is the first shopper, `shoppers[0].firstName` is the first shopper's name, `"a"`,  and `shoppers[1].email` is the second shopper's email, `"z@example.com"`, etc. `shoppers[0].items[2]` is the first shopper's third item, `"eggs"`.

Comment: @Jan, if this is your artwork on your website, you're a very good artist. A+

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `new` operator to instantiate a constructor:

```js
function Shopper(str) {
  this.items = str.split(', ');
  this.first_name = this.items[0];
  this.last_name = this.items[1];
  this.email = this.items[2];
}
var str;
while(str = prompt("Please enter...")) {
  var instance = new Shopper(str);
}
```

Comment: Surely parsing of the input shouldn't be the responsibility of the class constructor like that.

Comment: Probably true, but here the parsing is so simple that I don't think it matters much.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the assignment that says that you have to use `prompt`. It just says.

> Your JavaScript program should parse the user’s inputs.

Here is a javascript program which uses a HTML form to create objects.

```js
var form = document.forms[0];
var btn = document.getElementById("create");

btn.onclick = function(event){
  var shopper = {
    first_name: form.first_name,
    last_name: form.last_name
  };
  
  console.log(obj);
  
  event.preventDefault();
};
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.2/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form id="shopper_form">
  
  <div class="row">
    <label>First name</label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name"/>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <label>Last name</label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name"/>
  </div>
  
  <a class="button" href="#" id="create">Create</a>
</form>

<div id="test"></div>
```